# sencha keeps session cookies from development version and compiles with ipa

Tags: ios, facebook, session, sencha-touch-2, session-cookies

I have an app that uses sencha stores for keeping a users session which is fine and works well but upon building for iOS i found that other users checking the app when passed the ipa were automatically logged in as me and also had access to my Facebook as it seeming has stored the session db from the emulator and packaged it with the app.  How can I delete this session and ensure that the session is not passed in the ipa??

This is a very serious issue indeed

Comment: Why not use localstorage instead?

Comment: Ah, you're using a localstorage proxy then. I misunderstood.

Comment: do you build for iOS in Xcode with sencha touch 2.3 ? and if so have you ever seen your local storage values carry in the ipa build?